# Electronic Devices

Tags: transistors

Below I am attaching the circuit I'm trying to simulate, the question at hand, and my solution so far that does not seem to be correct. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. When I simulate the circuit I have built, I get values that do not correspond to the values detailed in the lab manual even though my hand calculations seem to add up. For example, the lab manual asks us to have Vc= +5V. In the hand calculations we performed, we get this but when I run the simulation, I get Vc= +10V. Are we correct in using the NPN transistor built into LTSpice or do we need to download a different version of the NPN transistor online? Have I correctly built the circuit? Are my values for the resistors off? I have tried building the circuit a few different ways but the one I am attaching below makes the most sense for me. Please refer to the images attached.[image: question at hand]
[image: my LTSPice build]

Comment: LTspice has a lot of NPN transistor models, right click on the transistor and click "pick new transistor" and you'll find a long list of built-in models. Pick one that better represents what you used in your hand analysis; the default model is very rarely appropriate for anything because it represents a tiny transistor that would be used internal to an IC.

Comment: Show us your "hand calculations" -- there's probably an error. Just glancing at the circuit, the base is biased at 0V, so there's about 0.5 mA through the emitter resistor, and this current is only going to create a 5 V drop across the collector resistor. So there's nothing obviously wrong with the simulation.

Comment: You should use a real transistor model  (eg. 2N3904) but clearly the ratio of values of R3 vs. R4 are not correct with the given values of R1/R2. With R3 =10kΩ  Ic will be at the design value with a Vc of 5V, so your other calculations are suspect.

Comment: I actually disagree with my fellow colleagues here about picking an actual part#. I think in this specific instance with a homework question like this that uses idealized parts you should use the default model. However, you should be aware that you got lucky that the \$\beta\$ of the default model defaults to 100. If a homework question specifies a different \$\beta\$ (e.g. 300), you should know how to use a SPICE directive like `.model myNPN NPN(Bf=300)` and then rename Q1 to `myNPN`.  I do agree with @DaveTweed you should show us your hand calculations so we can find the discrepancy.